# Prop not loading on +page.svelte in svelte app

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

Hi I am trying to fetch some data from an API (FastAPI running on same localhost on a different port)

here is the +page.js code

```
/** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */

export async function load({ fetch }) {
    const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000');
    let message = await res.json()
    message = message.message
    if (res.ok) {
        console.log(message)
        return {
            message
        }
    }

    throw error("No data Received")
}
```

and here is +page.svelte:

```
<script>
    /** @type {import('./$types').PageData} */
    export let message;
</script>
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello World {message}</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae provident, labore qui modi minima voluptate perferendis est beatae non, molestias a, esse facilis deleniti error voluptatum iure harum magni debitis placeat ad! Amet numquam ratione iste?</p>
    </div>
</main>

<style>
    .container {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: justify;
    }
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

The console.log(message) in +page.js is logging the response but the {message} variable in +page.svelte component is undefined. what am i doing wrong.

PS: I am following the sveltekit docs from the official website.

Comment: I think you have to `export let data` instead of `message`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the props passed down from the various files (page.js, layout.js, ...) are now available in one big `data` prop.

```html
<script>
 export let data;
 // assign it to a variable yourself
 $: message = data.message;
</script>

<!-- or use it directly from data -->
<h1>Hello {data.message}</h1>
```

Comment: Are there cases where `page/layout.js`run again after opening the route, so data might change and it's better to declare it reactive or would it be fine to just `let message = data.message` or `let {message} = data`? (There's a difference with SSR?)

Comment: if you have a route `[slug]/..` and go directly from `/a` to `/b` the page component stays the same but `data` updates, so if you don't have reactivity your page will not update.

Comment: Thanks that clarifies a lot. we dont have to declare it as reactive if there only one page or no dynamic routes right?